# How to efficiently convert 2d numpy array into 1d numpy array of tuples?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286254/convert-list-to-a-list-of-tuples-python?rq=1) on going from a list to tuples using an iterator, but I'm dealing with a large data set.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806259/convert-list-of-list-of-tuples-into-2d-numpy-array) for going from tuples to a list, actually there's a bunch of questions going from list of tuples to an array, but I haven't found how to go the other direction...

I have:

```
np.arrray([[   0    1]
           [   1    1]
           [   2    1]
           ..., 
           [1004    3]
           [1005    1]
           [1006    1]])
```

I want:

```
np.arrray([(   0    1)
           (   1    1)
           (   2    1)
           ..., 
           (1004    3)
           (1005    1)
           (1006    1)])
```

I don't necessarily need a numpy array of tuples, but I want to do it effciently.

Comment: *I don't necessarily need a numpy array of tuples, but I want to do it effciently* - have you tried a regular list comprehension ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thanks for the quick reply. Isn't list comprehension the same as the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23286299/2876684)?

Comment: what can you do with a 1-d numpy array (or other sequence) of tuples that you can't already do directly with the 2-d numpy array?

Comment: @jez I need to feed it back into a Natural Language Processing library called [Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To efficiently vectorize this transformation, take the transpose

```
a = np.array([[   0 ,   1],
              [   1 ,   1],
              [   2 ,   1],
              [   0 ,   1],
              [   1 ,   1],
              [   2 ,   1] ])

at = a.T 

at= array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

then `zip` to convert the two 1D lists into a list of tuples

```
zip(at[0],at[1])
```

This will significantly be faster than a list comprehension

But in python 3.4

```
list(zip(at[0],at[1])

Out []:
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
```

EDIT: thanks to @Divakar

Possibly slightly faster by directly slicing : `zip(a[:,0], a[:,1])`

Comment: Faster by a factor of 3 on my system. Very cool outside-the-box solution!

Comment: Possibly slightly faster by directly slicing : `zip(a[:,0], a[:,1])`.

Comment: @SerialDev Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use some simple and direct Python and get a list (or whatever) of tuples:

```
list(map(tuple, arr))
```

where `map()` simply applies `tuple()` to each line of the array in turn.